# $ \sqrt[n+1]{a_{n+1}}$ with $a_{n+1}=n\cdot (1+\ln {a_n})$ with $a_1 =1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm given the sequence

$  \sqrt[n+1]{a_{n+1}}$
with $a_{n+1}=n*(1+\ln  {a_n})$ with $a_1 =1$

and I have to find the limit

$  \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}$.

I've tried calculating some elements of the sequence but 
I found no rule in the form of the general term $a_n$

Can someone give me some hints?

Comment: Numerically, it seems like the limit is $1$. Could there be a condition for a sequence $s_n$ so that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{s_n} = 1
$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we set $b_n=\ln a_n$, then $b_1=0$ and $b_n$ satisfies the recursion
$$
b_{n+1} = \ln n + \ln(1+b_n).
$$
It looks from this like $b_n$ should grow only logarithmically; and indeed we can prove by induction that $0\le b_n < 2 \ln n$. [The induction step requires us to verify that $\ln n+\ln(1+(2\ln n)) < 2\ln(n+1)$, and this is a slightly tedious but uncomplicated calculus exercise.] In particular,
$$
0 \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n}n \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2\ln n}n = 0,
$$
which shows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = e^{\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n/n} = 1.
$$
(In hindsight, one could have proved directly that $1\le a_n < n^2$ for all $n$ by induction.)